# Inserting data into SQL Server from a .sql file

Tags: sql-server

```
BULK INSERT dbo.table
FROM /tmp/tablename.sql;
WITH
    (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO
```

This results in an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server www, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '/'.

I have saved my .sql file in tmp folder and I used it in the FROM part of my command to insert the data in that sql file but I get that error shown above:

> Incorrect syntax near '/'.

What is the correct structure for this kind of insert in centOS command line

Also tried remocing the first `/` like `FROM tmp/tablename.sql;` I know this is wrong but I get same error

Comment: Put single quotes around the path.

Comment: I see in my mssql IDE it worked without the `''` Now i get error in `WITH` when I put `WITH;` i also get error.. What should I put in the `WITH` line @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes are present in your code.

1. Missing single quotes around the file path
2. `;` after the file name should not be present.

Query

```
INSERT dbo.table
FROM '/tmp/tablename.sql' --; removed && single quotes added
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```